# Add a feature for admins to send email to all users in Teams instance

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

It would be immensely helpful to be able to send communications via the teams instance, to every user on the teams instance. This would be especially effective in conjunction with the "Announcement" article type too - an "announcement" would be just that, and make an announcement to the users.

Right now, we're struggling to find a way to distribute a best practice guide to all users as they work across multiple distribution lists internally.

Comment: There's a kind of kludge you can use. Create a group that contains your entire team, then create the announcement and change the permission settings to be that group. Post it and then comment on it... everyone will then be notified with that comment and a link to that post. Then if needed - remove the group from permissions again... Horrible but might work for your purposes depending if/when this feature request is implemented.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks Jon - that's actually really useful. I appreciate your help. Hope something like this makes the roadmap going forward

Comment: Disclaimer - I think I've seen that happen on teams I'm a member of (but by accident) so might want to give it a test run as not 100% sure.